# Trouble getting shell script to work with simple conditional statement

Tags: shell

This is part of a bigger project but I can't get this part to work and I'm having a brain fart.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Do you wish to download/checkout the source code? > "
read text
if ["$text" = "Yes"]
then
    do something
else
    do something else
fi
```

It should simply be reading in what the user types and then go through a simple conditional. but I get this error

```
./check.sh: line 6: [Yes: command not found
```

I thought I had formatted the shell script correctly but I guess not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add spaces after brackets:

`if [[ "$text" = "Yes" ]]`

When performing operations on strings it's always a good idea to use double square brackets. It will make your code work properly with spaces and new lines.

Comment: Got it thanks! I didn't realize shell was that strict about spacing.

Comment: @Sempus, this is because `[` and `[[` are not mere syntax, they're actually commands. Therefore you need a space to separate the command name and the first argument. From a bash session, type `help [`